# Missing folder vendor and file .env after creating new laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

[this is my cmd code and there's something missing after creating laravel project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNnx.png)

[this is my laravel project, vendor folder and .env are missing after create this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5uuv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in your console:

```
composer install
cp .env.example .env
```

[More about composer](https://getcomposer.org/)